# is it possible to extract 'LifeCycle Status' using emcli ( Oracle Enterprise Manager )

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

It's easy to set the LifeCycle status ( and other properties ) with emcli,

```
emcli set_target_property_value -property_records="sometestdatabase:rac_database:LifeCycle Status:Test"
```

but getting the current values isn't clear - I'm not seeing a verb in the reference.

Is the only way via SQL against the repository?

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it's not possible, but, for the record, here's to get get the information via SQL.

```
SELECT CASE INSTR ( cm_target_name, '_' )
WHEN 0 THEN cm_target_name
    ELSE SUBSTR ( cm_target_name, 0, INSTR ( cm_target_name, '_') - 1 )
END database_name, property_value
FROM sysman.cm$em_tprops_ecm_view
WHERE cm_target_type = 'oracle_database'
AND property_name = 'orcl_gtp_lifecycle_status';
```